# How do I bind a report field in Report_Open when I build the record Source on the fly?

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

For an existing report, I build the record source in the Report_Open event, so that it looks like this (it varies according to values passed in OpenArgs):

```
> SELECT tblSpecies.commonname AS Species,
>        Month(tblLocationVisit.VisitDate) AS qMonthNumber, 
>        MonthName(Month(tblLocationVisit.visitdate)) AS qMonth,
>        (SUM(Nz(tblSighting.Adults)) + SUM(Nz(tblSighting.Emerging))) AS TotalAdults, 
>        tblSighting.SpeciesID    FROM tblSpecies INNER JOIN
>                    ((tblSite INNER JOIN tblLocationVisit ON tblSite.ID = 
         tblLocationVisit.SiteID) 
>                    INNER JOIN
>                      tblSighting ON tblLocationVisit.ID = tblSighting.LocationVisitID) ON 
>                      tblSpecies.ID = tblSighting.SpeciesID    GROUP BY  
                       tblSpecies.commonname, Month(VisitDate), MonthName(Month(visitdate)), 
>                      tblSighting.SpeciesID    HAVING (((SUM(Nz(tblSighting.Adults)))>0) OR 
                       (SUM(Nz(tblSighting.Emerging)) > 0));
```

Species, MonthName, TotalAdults and a sum of TotalAdults are the only values presented in the report and it all works.
In the design sheet for the report, there is a static query given as the Record Source but this is replaced in the Report_Open event, as described above.
The static query exists purely for binding the report fields.

I now want to add a count to the report, so that:

```
> SELECT COUNT(tblLocationVisit.ID) AS qVisitCount,
>        tblSpecies.commonname AS Species,
>        Month(tblLocationVisit.VisitDate) AS qMonthNumber, 
>        MonthName(Month(tblLocationVisit.visitdate)) AS qMonth,
>        (SUM(Nz(tblSighting.Adults)) + SUM(Nz(tblSighting.Emerging))) AS TotalAdults, 
>        tblSighting.SpeciesID    FROM tblSpecies INNER JOIN
>                    ((tblSite INNER JOIN tblLocationVisit ON tblSite.ID = 
                      tblLocationVisit.SiteID) 
>                    INNER JOIN
>                      tblSighting ON tblLocationVisit.ID = tblSighting.LocationVisitID) ON 
>                      tblSpecies.ID = tblSighting.SpeciesID    GROUP BY  
               tblSpecies.commonname, Month(VisitDate), MonthName(Month(visitdate)), 
>              tblSighting.SpeciesID    HAVING (((SUM(Nz(tblSighting.Adults)))>0) OR 
               (SUM(Nz(tblSighting.Emerging)) > 0));
```

The new query works when run standalone; there is no "Order By" in the property sheet for the query.
I have replaced the static query in the report's Record Source with the new query including the Count; I have also added code so that the
Report_Open event adds the Count to the record source. The new report field, xVisitCount, is bound to qVisitCount in the static query.

On running the report, I am asked to "Enter Parameter Value" for xVisitCount, so the binding isn't working; whatever I enter there, appears in the report.

If I remove the control source for the new field, there is no "Enter Parameter Value" prompt and the report field values are blank.

I think I need to change the binding for the new display field (xVisitCount) during the Report_Open event, either before or after assigning Me.RecordSource but I don't know how to do this.

I developed the original project a couple of years ago and my MS Access, while never very strong, is now very rusty. I have tried to format the code sensibly but I'm not sure it will display very well - I may have even trashed the accuracy of the code but I'm hoping this won't prevent your understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Access asks for the value of `xVisitCount`, it looks for this field in the record source.

To avoid any confusion, you should name the field the same everywhere, e.g. `qVisitCount`:

1. in the static query
2. the report field Name
3. the report field ControlSource
4. in the dynamic query.

See also [How to debug dynamic SQL in VBA](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1099570/3820271) - copy your created SQL to a new query to make sure it returns the fields and data you expect it to.